# radiobutton select one corresponding to column

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

I have two radio button in two column of gridview.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Recommend">
<ItemTemplate >
  <asp:RadioButton ID="rdRecommend" runat="server" onclick="javascript:CheckOtherIsCheckedByGVID(this);" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approve" Visible="false">
<ItemTemplate >
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdApprove" runat="server"  onclick="javascript:CheckOtherIsCheckedByGVID(this);"/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

But if i selected in Recommend column then radiobutton approved column is deselected

Comment: means you want to select only one radio button at a time means if Recommend is selected and u select Approve one then Recommend one deselected automatically and Approve one selected.something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use GroupName property of radio buttons with same name.Like
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Recommend">
<ItemTemplate >
  <asp:RadioButton ID="rdRecommend" runat="server" GroupName="rec" onclick="javascript:CheckOtherIsCheckedByGVID(this);" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approve" Visible="false">
<ItemTemplate >
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdApprove" runat="server" GroupName="rec"  onclick="javascript:CheckOtherIsCheckedByGVID(this);"/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I think it will help for you..